# How to reload table view from another view controller via appDelegate in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, tableview, appdelegate, reloaddata

I'm trying to reload my SingleGrid's `UITableView` from my FirstViewController. 
`UITableView`'s declaration is `IBOutlet` and singleGrid variable declared in my AppDelegate. 
I want to reload singleGrid's `UITableView` from FirstViewController.Table view name `singleGridTable` isn't coming after dot.

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate.singleGrid.singleGridTable reloadData]
```

Comment: @shehzad ali i didnt understand what do you mean? This code in my FirstViewController and also i write this top of firstViewController's viewdidload: AppDelegate *appDelegate= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: your singleGridTable is declared as a property in SingleGrid's .h file? 
`@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView * singleGridTable;`

Comment: It is declared in SingleGrid.m's top like this // SingleGrid.m file
@interface SingleGrid ()

property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutleT UITableView *singleGridTableView;

end

Comment: Move it to .h file. It will become public then and will be visible to your firstViewController.

Comment: Ok i will try thanx a lot

Comment: Have you tried the solution? Does it work?

Comment: yes i have tried now i can see singleTableGrid after dot but it is not reload :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have declared singleGrid as a property in your appdelegate.h like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SingleGridViewController * SingleGrid;
```

Those properties which are declared in .h files are public otherwise they are private and you can't access them in other classes.

Also make sure singleGridTable is also declared as property in your .h file.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView * singleGridTable;
```

Comment: it is ok but after nsurlsession request in nsurlsessin block i write this but not work table is not reload                     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [appDelegate.singleGrid.singleGridTable reloadData];
                    });

Comment: Make sure instance datasource and delegate of singleGridTable should be set against the instance of singleGrid.

Comment: in my FirstViewController's init I write: singleGridTable.delegate = self; singleGridTable.dataSource = self; Did you mean this ?

Comment: Add breakpoint in NSURLSession response and check if singleGrid exists? if it exists check singleGrid.singleGridTable.delegate; you can use commands for this in debugger  `po appDelegate.singleGrid;`  then `po appDelegate.singleGrid.singleGridTable.delegate;`

Comment: singleGridTable is exist but not entered dispatch_sync block appDelegate.singleGrid.singleGridTable
<UITableView: 0x7fd15b034600; frame = (20 230; 280 234); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd158f39e40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd158f34c30>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {280, 0}>

Comment: Update code of your NSURLSession in your problem mentioned above and also share the log of response coming from server.

Answer (score 0):

More code might help (relevant headers and implementations), but I can take a shot in the dark. Does firstViewController know about what properties would exist on a SingleGrid? Where ever you would want to access a property on SingleGrid you'll need to include the header that declares that the property exists. So does your firstViewController ha